# MATLAB 3D matrix, max in different directions + rotation using MIP

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, max

I have a 3D image called `img`, let's say it is a 291x287x801 int16 array. I am using the MIP (Maximum intensity projection) to find the image with the maximum intensity in different directions. I know that I could use `max` to get the MIP:

```
MIPimg=max(img,[],3);
imagesc(MIPimg);
```

However, this is not giving me the right direction. I think it is along the z-direction, but what should I do if I want to find the MIP along the y or x direction?

I did try to change that 3 which indicates dimension to 1 or 2, but MATLAB tells me

> Error using image
>   Color data must be an m-by-n-by-3 or m-by-n matrix.

when calling `imagesc(MIPimg)`.

I also tried `MIPimg=max(img,[ ],[2 3]);` but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `max`? What does the `3` mean in that bit of code you post?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I did. that 3 is the dimension. I did try to change that to 1 or 2, but MATLAB tells me                                                                                             
         Error using image
Color data must be an m-by-n-by-3 or m-by-n matrix.                                                                                   and then I tried MIPimg=max(img,[ ],[2 3]); but still no good

Comment: That is good information to [edit] into your question. Show exactly what you did when you received that error. Was it the `images` call that throws the error? It cannot have been `max` itself. `images` is not a MATLAB function that I can find. Is this something you wrote yourself or got from somewhere? Please indicate what it does. See [mre].

Comment: Thanks so much! I used imagesc. image was a typo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `imagesc` expects either a 2D array as input, or a 3D array where the 3rd dimension has exactly 3 values (this is the way MATLAB represents an RGB image). When you do `max(img,[],1)`, you get an 1x287x801 array back, which has 801 elements along the 3rd dimension, not 3 as MATLAB expects.

What you need to do for display is to convert this 1x287x801 array into an 287x801 array. The function [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) does this (it removes all dimensions with size 1):

```
MIPimg = squeeze(max(img,[],1));
```

Comment: Thanks you! That is very helpful! And do you have any idea of what to do about the rotation?

Comment: @March2020: Please don't change your question once it has been answered. Instead, ask a new question. Also, please keep each post to a single question, multiple questions in a post as not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
% create random 3D-unit8-matrix (to mimic an image)
img = uint8(randi(255,10,12,3)); % 10x12x3 matrix
% maximum over all rows (direction 1) of each of the 3 10x12 matrices => returns 3 1x12 arrays
[val,idx] = max(img,[],1); % default direction
% maximum over all columns (direction 2) of each of the 3 10x12 matrices => returns 3 10x1 vectors
[val,idx] = max(img,[],2);
% maximum over all slices (direction 3) of each of the 10x12 1x3 "depth" arrays => returns a 10x12 matrix
[val,idx] = max(img,[],3);
```

overall maximum

```
max(max(max(img))) % no useful information about the position
```

position of maximum:

```
[val_slc,idx_slc] = max(img,[],3); % I can better think in 2D
[val_row,idx_row] = max(val_slc);
[val_col,idx_col] = max(val_row);
idx_max = [idx_row(idx_col),idx_col,idx_slc(idx_row(idx_col),idx_col)];
```

check

```
assert( max(max(max(img))) == img(idx_max(1),idx_max(2),idx_max(3)) )
```